# How to convert all *.potx files to *.pptx files with VBA?

Tags: vba, loops, converters, powerpoint

I have a folder of ~20 *.potx files and I would like to convert all *.potx files to *.pptx, then delete the *.potx files.

Comment: *.potx are template files, are you sure you don't want to just create new presentations from the templates?

Comment: To me, converting to *.pptx and creating new presentations sounds like the same thing. I am compiling multiple file types to one PDF using Adobe Writer and *.potx files won't compile. Considering the other files types, it would be ideal for the current *.potx files to be converted to *.pptx with the same file name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will loop through all your templates, convert, and delete the template files.

```
Sub loopFiles()

    Dim fso As New FileSystemObject
    Dim fil As File
    Dim fold As Folder

    Set fold = fso.GetFolder(yourFolder)

    For Each fil In fold.Files

        If InStr(1, fil.Name, ".potx") > 0 Then
            Application.Presentations.Open fil.Path
            ActivePresentation.SaveAs Replace(fil.Path, ".potx", ".pptx"), ppSaveAsDefault
            ActivePresentation.Close

            'if you truly want to delete them, don't recommend since they are .potx
            fil.Delete True
        End If

    Next fil

End Sub
```

Comment: I get the following error: ---> Compile Error: User-defined type not defined

Comment: you have to add a reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime under Tools > References

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this: (replace YOUR FOLDER HERE with your folder name)

```
Public Sub ConvertPP()
  Dim pApp As Object
  Set pApp = CreateObject("Powerpoint.Application")
  Dim sFile As String
  Dim sFolder As String
  sFolder = "YOUR FOLDER HERE"

  sFile = Dir(sFolder & "\*.potx")
  Do Until sFolder = ""
    pApp.Presentations.Open sFolder & "\" & sFile
    pApp.ActivePresentation.SaveAs sFolder & "\" & Replace(sFile, "potx", "pptx"), 11
    pApp.ActivePresentation.Close
    sFile = Dir()
  Loop
  pApp.Quit
  Set pApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: `Kill sFolder & "\" & sFile` after `pApp.ActivePresentation.Close` to delete the file.